# Do I have to rewrite every case class in Sangria schema to expose in graphQL?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

imagine I have this as my schema, where people query with a bird Id and if they ask for the location they get everything about the location. Do I still have to define Location in "schema" format? or is there any way to use the case class immediately here?

If you want a bit of background about why I want to this:
I got a JSon-schema that is massively nested and it will be very close to impossible to manage every level of it. I am happy with the user requesting a top layer element which will return what ever case class is defined at that stage.

```
import sangria.schema._

case class Location( lat: String, long: String )
case class Bird( name: String, location: List[Location] )

class BirdRepo {
  def get(id: Int ) = {
    if( id < 10 ) {
      Bird( "Small",
        List( Location("1", "2"), Location("3", "4")
      ))
    } else {
      Bird( "Big",
        List( Location("5", "6"), Location("7", "8")
        ))
    }
  }
}

object SchemaDefinition {
  val Bird = ObjectType(
    "Bird",
    "Some Bird",
    fields[BirdRepo, Bird] (
      Field( "name", StringType, resolve = _.value.name ),
      Field( "location", List[Location], resolve = _.value.location)
//                       ^^ I know this is not possible
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Tyler mentioned, you can use `deriveObjectType`. The definition for both types will look like this:

```
implicit val LocationType = deriveObjectType[BirdRepo, Location]()
implicit val BirdType = deriveObjectType[BirdRepo, Bird]()
```

`deriveObjectType` is able to correctly handle `List[Location]` as long as you have an **implicit** instance of `ObjectType[BirdRepo, Location]` (`LocationType`  in your case) defined in scope.

> Field( "location", List[Location], resolve = _.value.location)

The right syntax would be:

```
Field( "location", ListType(LocationType), resolve = _.value.location)
```

Assuming that you already have defined `LocationType` elsewhere.

Comment: Its always nice when the author of the library shows up to answer the question :)

Comment: :D <3 StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, you should check out the section on [ObjectType Derivation](http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#objecttype-derivation)

Here is the example:

```
case class User(id: String, permissions: List[String], password: String)

val UserType = deriveObjectType[MyCtx, User](
  ObjectTypeName("AuthUser"),
  ObjectTypeDescription("A user of the system."),
  RenameField("id", "identifier"),
  DocumentField("permissions", "User permissions",
    deprecationReason = Some("Will not be exposed in future")),
  ExcludeFields("password"))
```

You will notice that you still need to provide the name, and then there are some optional things like the renaming of fields and depreciations.

It will generate an ObjectType which is equivalent to this one:

```
ObjectType("AuthUser", "A user of the system.", fields[MyCtx, User](
  Field("identifier", StringType, resolve = _.value.id),
  Field("permissions", ListType(StringType),
    description = Some("User permissions"),
    deprecationReason = Some("Will not be exposed in future"),
    resolve = _.value.permissions)))
```

Comment: I did see this, but this does not help me when there are cascading case classes right? If the user looked like `case class User(id: String, permissions: List[Permission], password: String)` then I'd need to "derive" `User` and `Permission` classes. I guess I will need to write some sort of code generator.